# NGINX Redirect www.website.com/folder/ to website.com

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redirect, subdirectory, multisite

Recently migrated a website out of `multisite network`(used ubuntu). Website was placed in subfolder and now is the exact, but root domain. How to change/redirect existing links, excluding /folder/ part?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 301 HTTP redirection, you can try

```
rewrite ^/folder(/.*) $1 permanent;
```

before the first `location` block.